# Battle Fader vs Majesty's Fiend

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Majesty's Fiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Majesty%27s_Fiend):

> Cannot be Special Summoned. Monster effects cannot be activated.

[Battle Fader](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_Fader):

> When an opponent's monster declares a direct attack: You can Special
>   Summon this card from your hand, then end the Battle Phase. If
>   Summoned this way, banish it when it leaves the field.

If Majesty's Fiend on field, can Battle Fader be special summoned and end battle phase by its own effect? I'm not sure if Battle Fader's effect is active or passive effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does more than just special summon, so it cannot be an inherent special summon.
That makes it a special summon by effect, which cannot be activated due to majesty's fiend.

Comment: I would just like to point out that "It does more than just special summon, so it cannot be an inherent special summon" is not valid reasoning - there are plenty of inherent special summons that also have some secondary part of the procedure (e.g. Quickdraw Synchron, the Kaijus, Spell Striker, Exodius, etc). The reason Battle Fader's effect is an activated effect is because of the colon indicating an activation timing.

Comment: The examples you mention are not effects, they are costs. Those can indeed be included in an inherent special summon. Sadly (especially with older cards) it is not always clear what is an effect or not.

Comment: Those are not costs OR effects, those are actual components of the summoning procedure.